# Style identification: How was this painting effect made?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, style-identification

I'm specially interested in the flowers in different colors.

Can they be achieved using a filter?

[image]

Image Source: [Robbi Robbins](https://www.flickr.com/photos/brillianthues/15550092618/in/pool-2151946@N21).

Answer (score 2):

The image seems to be an **actual painting**. You can achieve a similar effect using **Photoshop filters**, however the result will be noticeably artificial.

There are many ways to do this, I'd recommend you try with the `Oil Paint Filter`. [This tutorial](http://planetphotoshop.com/luminous-painting-effect-using-oil-paint-filter.html) has a step by step guide you can follow, although the basic principles are similar for any of these filters: Blur, Effect.

You can find the effect via `Filter > [Convert for Smart Filters >] Oil Paint`

Original image:

[image]

After applying some `Gaussian Blur`:

[image]

After applying the `Oil Paint Filter`:

[image]

Images source: [Mark S Johnson](http://planetphotoshop.com/luminous-painting-effect-using-oil-paint-filter.html).

Comment: @DumbNic There are definitely many ways to get a somewhat decent effect. Because the question doesn't state what the OP has tried I didn't want to go into too much detail, but please feel free to create a new answer!

Comment: To those who couldn’t find `Oil Paint`: It was removed from CC 2014. But there is a workaround for Windows: http://blogs.adobe.com/photoshopdotcom/2014/04/photoshop-spring-cleaning.html#oilpaint

Answer (score 1):

Following the link you provided, there is another link to the source image which looks like:

[image]

As I suspected before finding the source image, it is at least two different layers. You can see that because the umbrellas partially show through the overlaid flowers.

The different layers are highlighted rather crudely here:

[image]

My guess is:

The artist obviously extracted each umbrella to begin with.

Then warped the perspective towards a more central view.

Then positioned and rotated each into a comfortable position.

Then added a new layer with some flowers. Reduced the opacity so that the flower layer was slightly transparent.

Then applied a collection of filters, of which we cannot be sure unless the artist tells us themselves.

Possible Filters Used:

- Maybe a touch of `Posterisation`
- `Cutout` Filter
- `Dry Brush` Filter
- Perhaps a little bit of the `Watercolor` Filter
- And maybe the `Oil Paint` Filter as Yisela suggests

---

The best way to know for sure is to contact the artist. Even when they do tell you how they did it, it's unlikely you'll be able to follow the exact same steps with a different image and still achieve the same results. You may get some hints, but this kind of image effect can be produced many different ways, none of which will definitely work on a different image.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to answer ,i did ask the artist for general guidence,but none would even reply so here is some more links to 2 simmilar work by 2 artist 1:https://www.flickr.com/photos/timnoonan/13096588223/

tim noonan of flickr no. 2 is:https://www.flickr.com/photos/brillianthues/15385539554/     by  brillianthues and thank you for trying.